# How display a LinearLayout above a FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

My code XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#777777"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="00:00:00"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
            android:background="#000000" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_Rotation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/my_progress_interminate" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

How display TextView `txtTime` above `FrameLayout` the same button `button_Rotation`?

Comment: Since they're in a RelativeLayout, you can use layout_below  to make one thing layout below the other.  Or you can place them in a LinearLayout instead.

Comment: your frame layout's height is also match_parent. Change it to wrap_content if you to display them one below the other.

Answer (score 2):

I had fixed by move layout contain TextView down to under Framelayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#777777"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
            android:background="#000000" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="00:00:00"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_Rotation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/my_progress_interminate" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

outter linearLayout unless, then in your RelativeLayout
1st RelativeLayou:     android:layout_alignParentTop="true", and set an id(@+id/rl)
2nd FrameLayout:     android:layout_below="@id/rl"
3rd LinearLayout:     android:layout_below="@id/camera_view"

That's all! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is the easiest way to do it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FAFFD5" >
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/textlayout_outline"
        android:layout_margin="50dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/are_you_looking_for_something" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tap_here" />
    </LinearLayout>
```